# Extensions & Updates not working in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio 2015 community editor running on Windows 10 O/S. I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" each time I click on Tools -> Extensions & Updates.

How can I resolve this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try opening visual studio as administrator from start menu and then try the update in extensions menu.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Delete the contents from the following folders:

1. C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
2. C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

Comment: I would say rename these folder and if ur issue is resoved you can delete the folder else rename back to original name